# Using ElasticSearch Bulk to update and create documents dynamically?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I'm currently using `elasticsearch` and running a cron job every 10 minutes that will find newly created/updated data from my DB and sync it with `elasticsearch`. However, I want to use `bulk` to sync instead of making and arbitrary amount of requests to update/create documents in an index. I'm using the elasticsearch.js library created by elasticsearch.

I face 2 challenges that I'm uncertain about how to handle:

- How to use `bulk` to update a document if it exists and create a document if it doesn't within `bulk` without knowing if it exists in the index.
- How to format a large amount of `JSON` to run through `bulk` to update/create the document because `bulk` api expects the body to be formatted a certain way.

Comment: It depends on how you identify a document for the update/insert... Also, for bulk updates or inserts if it doesn't exist there is the upsert option: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#bulk-update. All depends on how you associate a DB record with an ES documents...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option when trying to stream in data from an SQL database is to use [Logstash's JDBC Input to do it for you](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-jdbc-input-plugin) ([the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html)). This can hopefully just do it all for you.

Not all SQL schemes make this easy, so for your specific questions:

> How to use bulk to update a document if it exists and create a document if it doesn't within bulk without knowing if it exists in the index.

[Bulk currently accepts four different types of sub-requests](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#docs-bulk), which behave differently than you probably expect coming from an SQL world:

- `index`
- `create`
- `update`
- `delete`

The first, `index`, is the most commonly used option. It means that you want to `index` (the verb) something to the Elasticsearch index (the noun). However, if it already exists in the index given the same `_id`, then it will replace it. The rest are probably a bit more obvious.

Each one of the sub-requests behaves like the *individual* option that they're associated with (so `update` is an `UpdateRequest` under the hood, `delete` is a `DeleteRequest`, and `index` is an `IndexRequest`). In the case of `create`, it is a specialization of `index`, which effectively says "add this if it doesn't exist, but fail it if is does exist".

> How to format a large amount of JSON to run through bulk to update/create the document because bulk api expects the body to be formatted a certain way.

You should look into using either the Logstash approach *or* any of the existing client language libraries, such as the [Python client](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py), which should work well from cron. The clients will take care of the formatting for you. One for your preferred language most likely already exists.

Comment: when using create within bulk must you specify an ID? Or can it have an arbitrary shaped data? Without the ID it can't recognize if the document exists or not?

Comment: No, but it's honestly kind of silly not to specify an ID with `create` because the benefit of `create` is that you get a notification that nothing was replaced in a fail-fast way (and, depending on the version of ES, you avoid doing work that is really a noop operation). Without an ID, it will generate a UUID for you and it's therefore not going to ever have a collision.